# Encoding video frames RGB to YUV_420_888 with MediaCodec | Android Camera2 API

Tags: android-camera2, android-mediacodec, yuv

I am encoding images to video using `MediaCodec`. I can find plenty of documentation online for converting YUV_420_888 format images into RGB for the purpose of receiving and processing frames from the Camera2 API using `ImageReader`. However, I am finding it difficult finding any documentation on how to convert RGB images to YUV_420_888 for encoding purposes - the issue is that this format is flexible and can represent any multitude of formats which isn't specifically provided by the encoder.

I have been able to encode frames by converting a bitmap into a YUV420SP image and sending the bytes to the encoder. However, on some devices the output video will be discolored or distorted, because the encoder is expecting a different format. I will be shocked if there is not a way to do this without writing hacky work-arounds for specific devices or encoders.

Here is how my video codec is set up:

```java
Bitmap frameBitmap; //this is initiated later in my app
final int VIDEO_BIT_RATE = 4000000; //min supported by Android for 1280x720
final int VIDEO_FRAME_INTERVAL = 1;
final int VIDEO_WIDTH = 1280;
final int VIDEO_HEIGHT = 720;
final int VIDEO_FRAME_RATE = 30;
//...
videoCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_MPEG4);
MediaFormat videoFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(videoMimeType, mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, selectColorFormat(videoCodecInfo, videoMimeType));
videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormatSelected);
videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, VIDEO_BIT_RATE);
videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FRAME_RATE);
videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, VIDEO_FRAME_INTERVAL);
videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 0);
//...
private static int selectColorFormat(MediaCodecInfo codecInfo,
                                     String mimeType)
{
    MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo
            .getCapabilitiesForType(mimeType);
    int selectedColorFormat = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length; i++)
    {
        int colorFormat = capabilities.colorFormats[i];

        if (isRecognizedFormat(colorFormat))
        {
            selectedColorFormat = colorFormat;
        }
    }
    return selectedColorFormat;
}
private static boolean isRecognizedFormat(int colorFormat)
{
    switch (colorFormat)
    {
        //I use YUV420Flexible - other values are deprecated.
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

and these are my two current approaches for writing to the encoder - I know they are both incomplete, this is for context only:

```java
int inputBufIndex = videoCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(timeout);
if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {

    //APPROACH A - using getInputImage
    currentVideoInputImage = videoCodec.getInputImage(inputBufIndex);
    assert currentVideoInputImage != null;
    ByteBuffer yBuffer = currentVideoInputImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer uBuffer = currentVideoInputImage.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer vBuffer = currentVideoInputImage.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
    yBuffer.put(yBytes);
    uBuffer.put(uBytes);
    vBuffer.put(vBytes);

    //or APPROACH B - writing the bytes directly
    currentVideoInputBuffer = videoCodec.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
    assert currentVideoInputBuffer != null;
    int remaining = currentVideoInputBuffer.remaining(); 
    currentVideoInputBuffer.put(data); //data is in YUV420SP format currently
    videoCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, remaining, presentationTimestamp, 0);
    totalFramesQueued++;

}
```

I thought about possibly obtaining a frame from the camera, detecting its row and pixel stride and using that to determine what the encoder might be expecting. But even then, I still don't know how to assemble the bytes, and also, I am not certain the encoder will expect the same format anyway.

Any help or point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Your snippet does not show the value of `colorFormatSelected`. Have you tried to set the value to `videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible );` ? See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible

Comment: Thanks @KompjoeFriek - I have added in my question the code I use to select color format. I am using `COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible` as you have suggested.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you try your approach A (copying the YUV channels individually), seems like should be a possible solution.

Comment: I did. I have managed to get approach A "working" but the problem is the planes of the Image provided by Camera are different in size to the Image provided by the encoder, so even though I have been able to write frames, it has strange pink or green lines through the image. @PerracoLabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ditched this approach completely and implemented a solution using OpenGL. Works a charm, but it was very hard to learn and took a long time to implement. My suggestion to anyone wishing to learn OpenGL is to start with the open source Grafika project. Link:
https://github.com/google/grafika

The best way to learn is to run the Grafika app, play around with its different activities, combine some of the concepts, etc.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for commenting on an old post, but I'm trying to do something similar. I need CPU/GPU access to the Frames though, and it looks like OpenGL only works in RGB - I need to support all 3; YUV/PRIVATE/RGB. Do you have any idea how that might work? 
See my post for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77157531