# Android Camera2: CPU/GPU access to Image data and MediaRecorder/MediaCodec in the same pipeline

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera2, android-mediacodec, mediarecorder

I am the maintainer of a popular cross-platform mobile camera library that can do preview, photo capture, video capture, and frame processing at the same time.
On iOS, this works perfectly.
But on Android, it actually seems to be impossible to do this with Camera2/`android.media` APIs.

On a high level, this is my structure:

[image: pipeline structure]

Important detail: The `VideoPipeline` would do Frame Processing/ImageAnalysis **and** Video Recording **in one**, aka synchronous.

- I need CPU/GPU buffer access to the native Frame
- I need the Frame format to be configurable (`YUV_420_888`, `PRIVATE`, `RGBA_8888`)
- I need it to be synchronous (aka MLKit Frame Processor runs first, then MediaRecorder/MediaCodec runs; that way I can apply stuff like face filters if needed)
- MediaRecorder/MediaCodec records the Frame to a h264/h265 video file (.mp4).

It seems like this is not possible with Camera2 at all, right?

Few potential solutions/ideas I had:

### 1. Separate outputs

Use separate Camera outputs, `MediaRecorder` and `ImageReader` - Does not work because the Camera only allows 3 outputs. We already have 3 (preview, photo, video).

### 2. Use `ImageReader`/`ImageWriter` to pass it through

[image: imagereader/imagewriter structure by passing it through]

This is the closest solution I had so far, and it seems like `ImageReader`/`ImageWriter` are really efficient as they are just moving buffers around (afaik at least). But there are multiple problems with this approach:

1. It does not work on every device. It is not guaranteed that `MediaRecorder`/`MediaCodec` can be fed with Images from an `ImageWriter`, so **sometimes it just silently crashes** ‍♂️
2. It seems like it requires the GPU flags to be set - API 29 only - but even those don't really work most of the time:

   ```kotlin
   val flags = HardwareBuffer.USAGE_VIDEO_ENCODE or HardwareBuffer.USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE
   val readerFormat = ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 // (can be YUV, PRIVATE or RGBA_8888)
   imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, readerFormat, MAX_IMAGES, flags)
   // ...

   val mediaRecorder = ...
   mediaRecorder.prepare()
   val writerFormat = readerFormat // or does this now need to be ImageFormat.PRIVATE???
   imageWriter = ImageWriter.newInstance(mediaRecorder.surface, MAX_IMAGES, writerFormat)

   imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
     val image = reader.acquireNextImage()
     if (isRecording)
       imageWriter.queueInputImage(image)
     else
       image.close()
   }, handler)

   configureCamera(imageReader.surface, ...)
   // later:
   mediaRecorder.start()
   ```
3. As far as I understand, it requires an additional conversion step from my format to whatever format the `MediaRecorder`/`MediaCodec` wants. So I might need an additional `ImageReader` that has the PRIVATE format:
   [image: long imagereader/imagewriter journey]

   ...which is just ridiculous.
4. It does not support Camera flipping (back <-> front) while recording, because the `width`/`height` of the Image Buffers might change and there is no scaling/resizing step in this pipeline.

### 3. Create a custom OpenGL Pipeline

Create a custom OpenGL pipeline that the Camera will render to, then we do a pass-through render pass to render the Frame to all the outputs:

[image: OpenGL structure graph]

But, this has four major drawbacks:

1. It's really really complex to build (I already built it, see [this PR](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/pull/1836), so not a real problem tbh)
2. It seems like this is not as efficient as a `ImageReader`/`ImageWriter` approach, as we do an implicit RGB conversion and an actual render pass, whereas `ImageReader`/`ImageWriter` just moving Image Buffers around (at least as far as I understood this)
3. It only works in RGBA_8888, as OpenGL works in RGB. This means, our frame processor (MLKit) does not work if it is trained on YUV_420_888 data - this is a hard requirement.
4. It is not synchronous, the `ImageReader` gets called at a later point. We could not really use information from the Frame to decide what gets rendered later (e.g. to apply a face filter).

---

At this point I'm pretty clueless tbh. Is a synchronous video pipeline simply not possible at all in Android?

My requirements:

- I have no problems with using C++/JNI for this
- Min API level doesn't matter. If it's 33 only, it is what it is.

I'd appreciate any pointers/help here, maybe I'm not aware of some great APIs. Thanks!